# Same volume for all MP3 Files in JAVA

Tags: java, playback, audio-player

I am writing an Java based Music Player which also should automatically change the volume levels of all mp3 to the same.

For example some mp3's are a bit louder than others and therefore I would like to have a player which automatically can adjust the volume levels to the same. So too quiet songs should be a bit louder and too loud songs should be more quiet. In the end they should be on the same level so that I do not have to change the devices volume.

I have searched the internet but didn't find any solution how to do this in JAVA.

Comment: You haven't found that because it doesn't exist.  You would need something that can analyze the waveform and "normalize" it on the fly.  That in itself would take up WAY too much in the way of resources.  You'll have to figure out how to normalize your volumes outside the app.

Comment: The problem isn't well defined. What does it mean for two audio files to be played equally loud? What if you have a recording with monotonic loudness and another that is mostly silent but with a sharp peak at some point?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called "[ReplayGain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReplayGain)" and is specified [here](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=ReplayGain_specification).

Tunes with nowadays masterings (see "[loundness war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness_war)") will have their volume lowered whereas older tunes will have their volume turned up so that the global perceived loundness stays the same.

Since the whole audio data is analysed to determine the value of the gain to apply, it is usually done once and then store as metadata (provided the audio format supports it, which is at least the case for MP3, FLAC, OGG and AAC).

It is implemented for instance in the free audio player Foobar2000, which does it quite efficiently, both track-wise and album-wise. Indeed, in some albums, it is a good practice to apply the same gain to all of its tracks when played as a whole.

The open source DJ software [Mixxx](http://www.mixxx.org/) provides this feature, so you should be able to find some piece of code related to ReplayGain in their repository.

In some cases of signals with low energy but high peaks, be careful to prevent clipping by either curbing the ReplainGain effect, or by adding a limiter at then end of the audio chain.

Comment: This was excactly i was looking for! Unfortunately Mixxx is written in C, but i would need some kind of libary or piece of code for java.

Comment: @zFr3eak https://www.google.com/search?q=java+replaygain Does not give any spectacularly great results, so you'll need to implement it on your own, or write a JNI wrapper around an existing native library. Good luck!